# replace black frames with previous frames

Tags: ffmpeg, filter, blackmagic

I have problematic footage from diving due to my camera/SD card - every 4th or so frame is just black, and I want to replace all those black frames with either an interpolation between the previous and next frame or just duplicate the previous frame.

I found this question ["remove black frames from vob files with ffmpeg"](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10383/remove-black-frames-from-vob-files-with-ffmpeg), but I don't want to cut out the frames but instead want to interpolate between the two frames or duplicate the previous frame.

I think I might be able to get all the relevant positions with the black-frame filters etc, but what kind of actions would I use to replace those frames with an interpolation or a duplicate of the previous frame in a fully automatic way (so I only pass my movie file into the script)?

All I've found so far is the "shuffleframes" method, which I could somehow (how?) feed with the position of the black frames and then thereby duplicate the previous frame.

Demo footage detailing the probem can be found [here](https://cl.ly/qCr1).

Comment: Highly related: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/13423/any-nice-tool-for-replacing-all-black-frames-in-a-video-with-another-frame https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/28407/replace-all-completely-black-frames-with-interpolated-frames

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to have the black frames removed and earlier frames duplicated.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf blackframe=0,metadata=select:key=lavfi.blackframe.pblack:value=50:function=less -vsync cfr -c:a copy out.mp4
```

The blackframe filter analyses and registers the proportion of a frame's pixels which are black. The metadata filter keeps all frames which have at most 50% of pixels black. The removed frames create a gap in the video stream. So by setting the video sync method to constant frame rate, ffmpeg duplicates earlier (non-black) frames to fill in those gaps.

You'll have to experiment with the metadata selection value `50` to get the right threshold.

Comment: This is amazing. It pretty much achieves what I wanted to (I think). I wonder though how it
a) handles cases where there is multiple directly following black frames
b) why the output files are consistently longer than the input files (duration wise)

Comment: why does the output have a longer duration than the input?

Comment: Share full log. How much difference are we talking about?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for the delay in replying. The difference is already some seconds, eg here https://pastebin.com/NfTVtEC0
original file: https://cl.ly/qSfM
ffmpeged file: https://cl.ly/qSMr

Comment: Don't see a difference. Mediainfo shows format duration for original: `3 s 532 ms` and for new file `3 s 534 ms`

Comment: Hmm, I aligned them in Final Cut and the top one is the transcoded one and it is longer. https://cl.ly/qSQr And this is only a 3s video... And the audio lines also look different https://cl.ly/qRvs 

Comment: Your source is variable frame rate. Apparently, FCP can't respect that - it conforms clips to constant frame rate. Which will reduce clip duration if there are frames with individual duration greater than `1/fps` seconds.

Comment: Rather than replacing with the most recent non-black frame, is it possible to have it interpolate the missing frames? \[Edit\] I've now asked [a new question for this](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/28407/replace-all-completely-black-frames-with-interpolated-frames)